# How to hide and show data from taxonomy data list?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a page that shows a list of same taxonomy items..
the item name,the author,and "read more" link appears.

How can I show the image of each item as well?

Comment: Is that a [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) or a taxonomy term page?

Comment: taxonomy terms listing

Comment: I did it like this ...Add relationship that references the taxonomy field you use in the content type.
Add a Taxonomy term: Term ID field in Views. Exclude it from output.
Add a Custom Text field in Views.
Under Rewrite Results check the Output this field as a link checkbox. In the link path use the token for taxonomy term id - [tid]. If you want to use the core page, just enter taxonomy/term/[tid].

Comment: Since your items have an image field attached, it should be available in your view's fields list. Search for that field by machine name or label. I consider that your view's base table is content.

Comment: no ! I cannot even theme that page

Comment: Update your question by answering these: (1) where is your image field attached to, taxonomy term or content type ? (2) the type of the view that you have implemented. Theming is an other story.

Comment: Oh its by editing the node.tpl